# react-google-login not calling onSuccess

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, google-authentication, react-google-login

In the following snippets I'm trying to implement google oauth into my webapp using npm react-google-login. When I try to sign-in, the popup appears, I select one of my accounts, then a loading circle appears and the popup closes. (Not sure if this is a crash). However, my googleSuccess function does not seem to be called as none of the things I've logged are appearing in the console. Closing the popup prematurely does log googleError in onFailure.
Does anyone know why my onSuccess callback might not be firing?

```
 const googleSuccess = async (res) => {
    console.log("In googlesuccess");
    try {
        console.log("G sign in success", res);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
        
};
const googleError = (err) => {
    console.error('Google sign in failed.', err);
};
```

```
<GoogleLogin
        clientId= //removed, but my client id is here in my actual code
        render={(renderProps) => (
            <Button className={classes.googleButton} color="primary" fullWidth onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled} startIcon={<Icon />} variant="contained">
                Google Sign In
            </Button>
        )}
        onSuccess={googleSuccess}
        onFailure={googleError}
        cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
/>
```

Comment: What is the error being printed on the console by the `googleError` function ? could you also provide for us to better understand the issue

Comment: @RyanAquino It's been a while since I've looked, but iirc no error message is logged until I manually close the client. The error for that (which I was referring to in the op) is just "Error: pop_up closed by user" or something like that.